# Windows Azure logging: WADLogsTable as Application logs?

Tags: windows, logging, azure

With the new changes in Diagnostics monitoring with November Windows Azure CTP, based on what I’ve seen with logging samples I have the following question:

Is it a best practice to just use WADLogsTable as the Application log table since you get a lot more baked in features around filtering and configuration etc.?

Or do we just have to create a new application log table?

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use that table since most tools today are bound to it. In theory other tables are possible though.

Another tip: use a different storage account for diagnostics. An interesting read on that is over at [David Makogon's blog](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2010/08/azure-tip-of-day-separate-diagnostic.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice diagnostics tools available today that make use of querying the WADLogsTable.  Check out Cerebrata's Azure Diagnostics Manager.